# Properly building my MySQL JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I have 2 tables from which I'm trying to pull data from together in 1 query.

```
Guilds:
id (int) | guild (varchar)

Challenges:
id (int) | challenger (int) | challengee (int)
```

The "challenger" and "challengee" fields reference a "id" from the Guilds table. Using one query, I'd like to pull the Guild field for both the "challenger" and "challengee" (based on the "guild id"), but am stuck on the correct syntax to use.

```
SELECT challenges.`id` AS c_id, challenges.`challengee` AS c_challengee, challenges.`challenger` AS c_challenger, guilds.`guild`
FROM challenges
LEFT JOIN guilds
ON challenges.`challengee` = guilds.`id`
```

Is it possible building a query that would grab both the "challenger" and "challengee" Guild (field)?

An example of the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
challenge_id  |  challenger  |  challenger_guild  |  challengee  |  challengee_guild
-------------   -------------  ------------------  --------------  -----------------
2             |      8       |  oBsolete          |      5       |  Plague
```

Comment: Both the "challenger" and "challengee" will have same "guild" for one challenge?

Comment: no, the name will be different. overall i'm unsure if what i'm trying to accomplish is even possible, and if using 2 queries to gather my data is the only option

Comment: So are you trying to get guild for challengee and guild for challenger in one row?

Comment: yes, that is correct Aziz

Comment: challenger_guild  and challengee_guild go from Guilds.guild with other information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT t.id, t.challenger, t.g_challenger, t.challengee, g2.guild as g_challengee
FROM (
  SELECT c1.id, c1.challenger, g1.guild as g_challenger, c1.challengee
  FROM Guilds g1
  JOIN Challenges c1
  ON g1.id = c1.challenger
) t 
JOIN Guilds g2
ON g2.id = t.challengee
```

**Working Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e036d0/18

Comment: thank you so much Aziz! knowing this syntax opens a lot of doors for me now. this is fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SELECT Guilds.id
     , Guilds.guild
     , chas.challenger
     , chal.challengee
  FROM Guilds
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN Challenges as chal
    ON chal.challengee = Guilds.id as xxx_challengee
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN Challenges as chas
    ON chas.challenger = Guilds.id as xxx_challenger
ORDER 
    BY Guilds.id
```

not sure if it will work

Comment: no luck with that exact syntax, but will keep working on it. thank you Nazaret2005